# Lightweight provably secure design

Tags: symmetric, authentication, meet-in-the-middle-attack, lightweight

Is it possible to device lightweight (i.e. without asymmetric crypto and PKI; and without third party Trent) provably secure (in the exact security sense) scheme? Were there any attempts? Is it possible to make entity authentication using only one pre-shared secret key without MitM attacks?

---

Some remarks. By exact security I mean [concrete security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_security) approach (by Bellare and Rogaway).

By entity authentication I mean to prove that it is me who interacts with device. MAC is not an option because everyone who can intercept my message can pretend that he is me actually.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Would you please clarify what do you mean without public key infrastructure and secure against MitM attack? I suspect you wanna use the symmetric key schemes to authenticate a message and the most relevant approach is the MAC (Message Authentication Code).

Comment: Is "device" intended to be "devise"? Do you use "lightweight " in the sense it has in the tag (_Small and/or fast ciphers and other cryptographic primitives designed for use in constrained environments, such as embedded MCUs and smart cards_)? Bellare and Rogaway's concrete security assumes a crypto primitive modeled as PRP or PRF; are you willing to assume that? If so, is there anything wrong with the classical entity authentication using challenge/PRF/response//check?

Comment: Yes, by lightweight I mean these TAG things. What do you mean by "classical" challenge-response? Imagine the situation: TAG wants to prove me that it posesses some secret key K. I generate random number R as challenge and send it to TAG. I want to get back something of the form E_K(R), right? But it is possible that there is some adversary, who can intercept messages. Then he can "catch" the message E_K(R) from TAG and pretend that it was him who generate this message, and there is no method for me to check who really generate the response.